# Open application from command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, notepad++, windows-10

I want to open two applications on my computer through a batch file on Windows 10. I want to open them so that their positions split the screen in half vertically when I open the batch file. I have:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++
START "Notepad++" notepad++.exe
cd %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%%windir%\system32\
START "Command Prompt" cmd.exe
```

I'm not familiar with console commands or anything like that. I have been able to get the command prompt where I want it through changing its defaults. I can't seem to find anything similar for Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control that in Batch without the help of another program or tool. AutoHotkey could do it with a little coding. You can also find some tools at http://alternativeto.net/software/autosizer/.